# dropdownlist element inside jquery dialog doesn't get selected

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, dialog

I am in a situation. I have a dropdownlist inside jquery dialog. On click of some link, i retrieve data and set the text of textboxes inside the jquery dialog. All the text are set, during setting this value i also make the value selected for dropdownlist, which doesn't work?

Please help.

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in dropdownlist the value did not have any space but the selected value to be set had space. After removing the space it worked fine.

Thanks for taking time to look at this question.